# Declaring an array as property then pass as props to a child component in Typescript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core

I have to class components. One parent, one child. On parent, I have an array that needs to be declared as property then pass to child component as props.  Here's the code using Reactjs without typescript:

Parent Component:

```
import Fruits from './Fruits'

export default class Header extends Component {
   constructor(){
      super()
      this.state = {
         lists: []
      }
   }

   componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({
         lists: [{
            itema: 'apple',
            itemb: 'banana',
         }, {
            itema: 'orange',
            itemb: 'apple',
         }, {
            itema: 'banana',
            itemb: 'pear',
         }]
      })
   }

   render(){
      return(
         <div>
            <Fruits lists={this.state.lists} />
         </div>
      )
   }
}
```

Child Component:

```
export default function Fruits(props) {
   return(
      <div>
         {props.lists.map((v,i) => {
            return(<div>
               <span key={i}>{v.itema}, {v.itemb}</span>
            </div>)         
         })}
      </div>
   )
}
```

How do you convert this type to typescript?
I'm a typescript newbie.  And for a newbie, this brings headache.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly straightforward use of interfaces. Changed it slightly as you're not using props.

```
interface IStateList {
  [key: string]: string;
}

interface IState {
  lists: IStateList[];
}

export default class Header extends Component<{}, IState> {
  state: IState = { lists: [] };
  // No need for constructor since you don't do anything with props/state
  ...
```

Then for the Fruits:

```
interface IStateList {
  [key: string]: string;
}
interface IProps {
  lists: IStateList[];
}

export default function Fruits({ props }: IProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.lists.map((v: any, i: number) => {
        return (<div>
           <span key={i}>{v.itema}, {v.itemb}</span>
        </div>)         
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you can see there is a shared interface IStateList, which you could abstract out and import into both. I'd suggest changing the name from IStateList to something more semantic that both can use (one is used for state, one is used for props).

Comment: So in typescript, there's no need to include setState? Also, where would I store the array?

Comment: You would need setState() if you wanted to add/remove things from state, yes. You'd have to include all the normal functions to handle that as you see fit, but would essentially be no different than if it were javascript.

Comment: Hi. the object props and fat arrow after IProps is throwing back errors.

Comment: Got rid of the fat arrow. Updated code accordingly.